# Skyfield topocentric to ICRS transformation. Is there anything like SOFA / ERFA atic13?

Tags: transformation, astronomy, skyfield

I'm currently working on astronomy mount support tool. This need to transform coordinates between JNow and J2000. I've don this using the ERFA implementation in the SOFA library, which is also present in astropy. As I starting in looking after Skyfield for satellite tracking, I want to reduce the number of libraries used.
Actually the transformation from J2000 (or ICRS) to JNow (Topocentric) could be done on ERFA with "atic13" routine:

```
        rc, dc, eo = self.ERFA.atic13(self.ERFA.anp(ra * self.ERFA.D2PI /24 + self.ERFA.eo06a(jdtt, 0.0)),
                                      dec * self.ERFA.D2PI / 360,
                                      <topo julian date>,
                                      0.0)
        val1 = rc * 24.0 / self.ERFA.D2PI
        val2 = dc * self.ERFA.DR2D
```

The same way of doing that on Skyfield is

```
result = earth.at(<topo julian date>).observe(<coordinates>).apparent()
```

and I could access the coordinates from the result. Now what made me sad, because I might have on the wrong path, I would do it the other way round. So in ERFA it is simply:

```
            ri, di, eo = self.ERFA.atci13(ra * self.ERFA.D2PI / 24,
                                      dec * self.ERFA.D2PI / 360,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      <topo julian date>,
                                      0)
        val1 = self.ERFA.anp(ri - eo) * 24 / self.ERFA.D2PI
        val2 = di * 360 / self.ERFA.D2PI
```

but I don't find the right way with Skyfield. If somebody could direct me in the right way, this would be very helpful. I'm actually using the newest one (1.6)

Michel

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we know what you do with `astropy` and we can see to create the same results with `skyfield`.

Comment: The call `.observe(<coordinates>).apparent()` does many more things than simply transform the coordinate system — it also generates an entirely different kind of position, that's a different spot in the sky. Does the `atci13()` routine apply those transforms as well — light travel time and aberration, for example? The process of reversing it will be simpler or more complicated depending on what steps it takes.

Comment: Yes the ERFA routine (which is a MIT licensed version of the SOFA - http://www.iausofa.org - routines) does apply these transforms as well. They are accessible in astropy as well with import astropy._erfa as ERFA. I actually use the astropy calculations (python wrapper based on the underlying C implementation) because I would get out of my pure python written implementation of ERFA. I though I could moved the whole epoch transformations to skyfield, because one way does already work.

Answer (score 0):

Skyfield does not, alas, currently implement iterative approximations to the inverses of aberration and light deflection — it can only apply them in the usual, forward direction. By contrast, the ERFA routine you reference does indeed reverse them:

“Iterative techniques are used for the aberration and light deflection corrections so that the functions eraAtic13 (or eraAticq) and eraAtci13 (or eraAtciq) are accurate inverses; even at the edge of the Sun's disk the discrepancy is only about 1 nanoarcsecond.”

— [https://juliaastro.github.io/ERFA.jl/v0.4/api.html#ERFA.atic13-NTuple{4,Any}](https://juliaastro.github.io/ERFA.jl/v0.4/api.html#ERFA.atic13-NTuple%7B4,Any%7D)

You will want to keep using AstroPy for that transform.